# How to get video title and thumbnail from YouTube Playlist

Tags: api, youtube, playlist

I am trying to get Thumbnails, titles, and their description from YouTube Playlist. So, far I am able to get thumbnails but not sure how can I get titles and description. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="thumbnail"> </ul>
```

Script.js:

```
            var maxVideos = 5;
              $(document).ready(function(){
              $.get(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
                  part: 'contentDetails,snippet',
                  playlistId:'PLJYHm_ZxWCKnQmapkDs7x47jkr-nw3l50',
                  kind: 'youtube#videoListResponse',
                  maxResults: maxVideos,
                  regionCode: 'IN',
                  key: 'AIzaSyDI4rWo_wVAxRZEIgF6_8sRZDj8OCOZZ38'},
                  function(data){
                    var output;
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                      console.log(item);
                            thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
                      output = '<div id="img"><img src="' + thumb + '"></div>';
                      $('#thumbnail').append(output);
                    })

                  }
                );
            });
```

Here is the result I am getting:

[image]

Comment: No response from anyone? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As used

```
thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
```

just do some changes after snippet

as

```
title= item.snippet.title;
description= item.snippet.description;
```

I hope it really help you.

You can also go through [YouTube API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/) for more details